# Unsigned integer overflow in comparison expressions

Tags: c, if-statement, expression, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

In the C language, with this code snippet:

```
uint16_t a = 243;
uint16_t b = 65535;
uint16_t max = 65535;

if ((a + b) > max)
{
   printf("Out of range!");
}
else
{
   printf("Within range.");
}
```

The result will be "Out of range!". What type conversion rules apply in this case? Can someone point me to a documented source?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of range – integer promotions.

Comment: There is no overflow in this code on any architecture where `int` is more than 16 bits.

Comment: Implementation defined. NOT language defined.

Comment: The question has been edited. It originally asked what is the output of the program (and why). It now asks what rules cause the output to be "Out of range!".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 4 If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
> conversions are performed on them.

and (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 3 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
> conversions are performed.

and at last (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> 1. ... Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands.

and (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> 2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or
> unsigned int may be used:
> — An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or
> unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
> the rank of int and unsigned int.
> — A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
> by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
> otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
> integer promotions. 58) All other types are unchanged by the integer
> promotions.

So in the condition of the if statement

```
if ((a + b) > max)
```

all operands are converted to the type `int` according to the integer promotions. And an object of the type `int` is able to store the value of the integer expression `a + b` where each operand is in turn converted to the type `int`.

In fact the above if statement you may imagine the following way

```
if ( ( ( int )a + ( int )b ) > ( int )max )
```

or like

```
if ( ( ( unsigned int )a + ( unsigned int )b ) > ( unsigned int )max )
```

depending on whether the type `int` or `unsigned int` can store the values of the type `uint16_t`.

An overflow can occur if for example the size of the type `int` or `unsigned int` is the same as the size of the type `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 1):

If `int` is wider than 17 bits, `a`, `b`, and `max` will be converted to `int`. `a + b` will not overflow and will yield a result greater than `max`.

If `int` is 17 bits wide, `a`, `b`, and `max` will be converted to `int`. `a + b` will overflow, and the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

If `int` is 16 bits wide, `a`, `b`, and `max` will not be converted. `a + b` will wrap and will yield a result less than `max`.

Comment: Good catch on the 17-bit `int`.